# Count number of instances returned from a sql query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am looking for a way to count the number of times a result occurred for team X and a number of times a result occurred for team Y.

**Example**

I have a table containing a sports competition results from 2009 - present.
A user can query the DB to retrieve all results when selected 2 teams played against each other. 
The results gets displayed in tables as follows:
[image]

Now **I am looking for a way to calculate the total number of games played between the two selected teams, and how many time the result went in favour of (in this example) Stormers, and how many times the result went to the Sharks**

Is it possible to do this without changing data in my table table? Ive been trying to come up with some sort of logic to solve the above problem but I am stumped.

My code to retrieve data follows:

```
if($venue == "hometeam"){
        $result= " SELECT *
FROM `results`
WHERE `hometeam` = '$team1' && `awayteam` = '$team2'" or die(mysql_error());
    }

    else if($venue == "awayteam"){
        $result = " SELECT *
FROM `results`
WHERE `awayteam` = '$team1' && `hometeam` = '$team2'"or die(mysql_error());
    }

    else if($venue =="all"){
        $result = " SELECT *
FROM `results`
WHERE (`hometeam` = '$team1' AND `awayteam` = '$team1') OR (`hometeam` = '$team2' AND `awayteam` = '$team2')"or die(mysql_error());

    }
```

My code to display the data:

```
cho '<td>'.$row['gamedate'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['hometeam'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$row['awayteam'].'</td>';
            echo'<td>'.$row['homescore'].'</td>';
                echo'<td>'.$row['awayscore'].'</td>';
                if($row['homescore'] > $row['awayscore']){
                            echo'<td style="background-color:yellow">'.$row['hometeam'].'</td>';    
                }
                else echo'<td>'.$row['awayteam'].'</td>';
```

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
$rs = mysqli_query($link, "select * from results where result = \"Stormers\"");
$stormers = mysqli_num_rows($rs);

$rs = mysqli_query($link, "select * from results where result = \"Sharks\"");
$sharks = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
```

Now, variable $stormers will show the number of results matching Stormers, and Sharks will match results with Sharks.  You can also use the Count() MySQL function instead of select, but I was assuming you might want to get more data from it instead of just a number later on.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT `result`, COUNT(*) FROM `results` WHERE `hometeam` IN (`$team1`,`$team2`) AND `awayteam` IN (`$team1`,`$team2`) GROUP BY `result`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're iterating through the results to gen the table rows. Why not just count the wins up while you do that?

```
$homeTeamWins = 0;
$awayTeamWins = 0;
$ties = 0;
while( $row = $result->fetch_object() ) {
    if( $row->homescore > $row->awayscore ) {
        $homeTeamWins++;
    } elseif( $row->homescore < $row->awayscore ) {
        $awayTeamWins++;
    } else {
        $ties++;
    }

    // output the html rows
}
```